SSL certificate Common name does not equal DNS name
Recently I installed an SSL certificate on my server. When I checked the certificate the common name is not the name of my server however I can see that SAN does contain the correct details.
For example my webpage name is test.com the common name is test1.com and the san is test.com
When I load my webpage I do not see any errors however was wondering if it will cause any issues?
Apologies for the rudimentary question but when googling I get certificate name mismatch errors but I am not seeing this when I load test.com

The common name of the certificate has lowest priority for certificate verification when a san is available. The subjectAlternativeName is authoritative. See e.g. this question.

The use of the common name for the server identity was deprecated in May 2000. More than 24 years ago. Possibly before you were born :)
